# Why is this the expression for the rounding error in the three-point midpoint formula for the approximation of the first derivative?

Tags: numerical-methods, rounding-error, truncation-error

so I understand that in using the three-point midpoint formula,
$$f^{(1)}(x)= \frac{y_{+1}-y_{-1}}{2h} + \frac{e_{+1}-e_{-1}}{2h} - \frac{h^2}{6} f^{(3)}(\xi^*), \ \ \ \ \ \xi^* \in [a,b]$$

**round-off error:** $E_{round} = \frac{e_{+1}-e_{-1}}{2h}$

**truncation error:** $E_{trunc} = -\frac{h^2}{6} f^{(3)}(\xi^*)$

in order to find the optimal error of a point $f(x)$, when considering the round-off & truncation error, we must impose upper bounds on both $E_{round}$ & $E_{trunc}$. I get that this is because there's a 'sweet spot' at which the two combined errors $E_{total}$ is optimal.

So to derive an expression for optimal of $E_{total}$, in this [slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX2C1.png) from [here](https://math.okstate.edu/people/xzhang/F20Math4513/Notes/NA-Ch4-Student.pdf), we let $\varepsilon$ & $M$ be some numbers that represent the limits that allow for the optimal of $E_{round}$ & $E_{trunc}$ to be found.

I understand why the final expression for the truncation error is $E_{trunc} = \frac{h^2}{6}M$, but I don't understand why the round-off error is $E_{round} = \frac{\varepsilon}{h}$, specifically how the person in the slide jumped from
$$ \frac{|e(x_0 + h) - e(x_0-h)|}{2h} $$
to the following
$$ \frac{|e(x_0 + h)| + |e(x_0-h)|}{2h} $$
why can we add the errors $e(x_0 \pm h)$?

The solution is probably simple but here's some more context from [Burden's 'Numerical Analysis'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mDSj.png) just in case. Help is much appreciated

Comment: it is just an estimate of upper bound. once two errors are having opposite signs, then using a sum of absolute values is a usual treatment.

Comment: @Yimin could you elaborate? why is it a usual treatment in these cases?

Comment: @trxxns imagine in a case you have $e\left(x_{0}-h\right)=10^{6}$ and $e\left(x_{0}+h\right)=-10^{6}$. Say in another case you have $e\left(x_{0}-h\right)=10^{-8}$ and $e\left(x_{0}+h\right)=-10^{-8}$. Clearly the first case is much worse, but according to sum or errors the two cases are equally good.

Comment: What is that first formula, what is the context, what is $e_{\pm 1}$ in relation to $y_{\pm 1}$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann the formula gives a numerical estimation of the value of a differential $f'(x)$ when given a dataset $f(x)$, where $f(x)$ corresponds to $x$ separated by intervals of $h$. it's from the taylor expansion of the point $f(x \pm h)$, which is then rearranged & the first few terms of the rearranged expansion are used to estimate the value of a $f'(x)$ point. then all the residual terms make up the error of that $f'(x)$ estimation. it basically estimates the $f'(x)$ of a point $f(x)$ but using only the adjacent points $f(x \pm h)$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann except we round all $f(x \pm h)$ points to $N$ decimal places. so the formula actually uses the rounded version, $y_{\pm 1}$, of $f(x \pm h)$. so an adjacent point is $f(x+h)=y_{+1}+e_{+1}$, where $f(x+h)$ is the actual value, $y_{+1}$ is this value rounded & $e_{+1}$ is the rounding error. likewise, $f(x-h)=y_{-1}+e_{-1}$. the original formula with just the truncation error was $f^{(1)}(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}-\frac{h^2}{6}f^{(3)}(\xi^*)$ but introducing the rounded version of $f(x \pm h)$, the formula changes to the first equation in my original post. if that makes sense

Comment: If you could rework the start of the question to include this information, it would be so much clearer. // Then as said above, rounding errors are quasi random, so you can't know the sign, only make bounds on their magnitude and compute the best step size for the worst case.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I see that makes a lot more intuitive sense thank you! & I'll keep that in mind for future questions